# Python modules efficient organizing with Github

Tags: python, github, python-module

In short, how should I go about updating/organizing Python modules if I want to reuse them in multiple projects and share them on my team's GitHub?

I have a simple Python module with a few functions that I use frequently across different projects, and I also need to share my Jupyter notebooks on GitHub. I use this module there as well.

How do I organize my packages or import them at the beginning of my notebooks so that I store them only in one place and that they're available for people who want to re-run my notebooks on their clone of my code on our GitHub repo? I want to be able to update/add to my module from time to time, and I don't want to have to copy/paste the updated package across my team's different repos and all my local project foldes.

Comment: Have you read the [packaging guide](https://packaging.python.org/)?

Comment: You can upload to Pypi and people can install using pip. [Docs](http://peterdowns.com/posts/first-time-with-pypi.html)

Answer (score 0):

Create packages and then upload them to pypi. When someone need to use your code, can install with `pip install`. If your modules aren't opensource you can create an internal pypi repository.

You can also install modules just referencing the git repository `pip install git+git://github.com/jkbr/httpie.git`. Look at [Python packaging guide](https://packaging.python.org).